# Java Web Server, executing commands by URL

Tags: java, web-services

I am a rails dev and starting to learn Java. I'm interested in building a java web server and have it execute certain commands by url for instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/downloadFile?id=1000
```

Would tell the webserver to go download a file with the id of 1000 from another server.

Should I be using a framework like Play 2.0 or something?

Appreciate any help!

=============================================================================

For anyone looking for a simple solution:

https://github.com/perwendel/spark

Quick Example:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

import spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      get(new Route("/hello") {
         @Override
         public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            // Execute code here
            return "Hello World!";
         }
      });

   }

}
```

If you want to use url parameters you can simply call `request.queryParams("parameternamehere")`. So if I wanted to have that `/hello` route use `?name=john` to get the name, I would need to call `request.queryParams("name")`.

I was able to get this quickly running with IntelliJ, installed `com.sparkjava:spark-core:1.0` via maven, and then just created a new java class under /src/main/java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to do something similar, and used Dropwizard:

http://dropwizard.codahale.com/

It has a built in Jetty webserver, also includes Jackson for JSON. It was easy to set up, is easy to use, and I got up and running surprisingly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a servlet. Then, in the configuration for your webapp (basically, inside web.xml) you will specify a mapping from the URL (e.g. /downloadFile) to the servlet. That way, the web-server (e.g. Tomcat) will send the request to your servlet.

You can check out [Oracle's tutorial on servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).